# CSS background colour not extending to the edge of the screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style an application, but for some reason,  I cannot make the background of one of my classes extend to the edge of the screen.

I made a fiddle to show this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hydropotamus/krevheyc/

I think the problem is in this class:

```
.moving-background {
    left:-10%;
    padding-top:130px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#00a221;

}
```

As you can see in the fiddle,  the background colour doesn't extend to the edge of the screen,  and i am unsure of how to move forward with this.

I have tried switching the padding and margins as well,  but i can't figure out where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the margin from the body is set to 0.

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS add this:

```
body { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
```

Different browsers use different margin and padding defaults for the page; best to specify them.

Comment: Note: Adding a body tag to your fiddle and doing this solved the problem - not sure if it'll be that simple with the code in situ

Answer (score 0):

the 8px margin in the body is causing that.  Some of the css is whacky, but you could also add margin-left: -8px if you want to just change that one area and not affect the others.

```
.moving-background {
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

also, the reason why the top green section does not have that gap is because the position is fixed and left is 0% (should just be 0);

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that that element was in a container with some padding that I didn't notice.  I had to remove that padding and then it was able to work.   however,  i did try your solutions in the fiddle,  and it did work so thanks!